# OpenCV layout.xml namespace is not bound

Tags: android, opencv

I have seen in this tutorial(http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2018/02/programacion-opencv-para-android.html) how to use OpenCV for android for the first time. I have followed all the steps that come and I have the following erro in the XML of the layout of the main activity: Namespace is not bound.
Does anyone know how to solve it?
I leave the xml file of the pos layout if it helps.
Thank you very much.

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:id="@+id/cameraview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        opencv:camera_id="any"
        opencv:show_fps="true" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error: *Namespace opencv is not bound*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot:

```
xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

In your root Layout(`ConstraintLayout`).

Also, make sure the dependency of `org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView` is already added in your `Build.gradle`. Or at least, if you're importing the `jar` file manually, make sure you have the implementation of the library in your `Build.gradle` file.